# Symfony2 Functional Test check environment for performance purpose

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I'm trying to test my symfony2 controller, it is a big controller,  but the key point in my controller to be sure is that generated correct canonical url or not. My only functional test for this controller actions asserts this canonical url. My test's data provider testing this controller with ~400 urls. There are many search patterns this controller trying to handle.

I want to add something like following code to controller. Do you think is this wrong changing source code for testing purpose ? Or do you have any ideas how could I stop my controller and return the desired response instead of execute bunch of code to generate search result?

```
if ($this->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() == 'test') {
    return new Response(sprintf('<link rel="canonical" href="%s">', $canonicalUrl));
}
```

Update 1 :

Part of my controller action.

```
protected function unifiedSearch(Request $request, $isSluggedSearch)
{
    $searchService = $this->get("frontend.service.search");

    // get routes and their required parameters from route collection which routes start with "searchcontroller_"
    $routeCollection = $searchService->getSearchControllerRoutes("searchcontroller_");
    // get current route name.
    $currentRouteName = $request->get('_route');

    $parameterBag = new SearchParameterBag(
        $currentRouteName,
        // current route's parameters.
        $request->get('_route_params'),
        // current queryString parameters.
        $request->query->all(),
        // holds current route's required parameters.
        $routeCollection[$currentRouteName],
        // all routes with their respected paramaeters.
        $routeCollection
    );

    try {
        $parameterBag = $searchService->resolveUrl($parameterBag, $isSluggedSearch);

    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException($request->getUri());

    } catch (SearchNotFoundException $e) {
        $parameterBag->setCanonicalUrl($request->getUri());
        $searchResultNotFound = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: I think its wrong, this is faking the test, so why test? I think you should make a call which has a smaller result, this way you can test for real and do not forge it.
And putting a code like that which changes behavior accordingly to environment seems wrong to me.

Comment: Actually as a result of page, I already put canonical to page. In code there are at least 10 api calls and bunch of filters etc. it is detailed search page result. But I'm just testing whether incoming url pointing a correct canonical url or not ? if I don't add this ~400 urls and every url is a different case. 37 mins of test result. :/ Like that between 5 and 7 min. Just 1 api call required to solve some parameters.

Comment: The idea is to move the portion of the controller that checks for your canonical url into it's own service and then unit test just the service.  Move other portions of the controller code into their own service as well and test them.  You will end up with a thin controller which probably does not testing at all.  And yes, having the source code detect when it being tested is a bad idea.  Look at how much trouble Volkswagen got into.

Comment: The other approach is to inject mock objects into your controller.  But I suspect your controller is not really designed to make this easy.

Comment: @Cerad I added related part of my action. Could you give me an idea how to pass mock object properly in functional test ? $searchService->resolveUrl do lots of things to find unique search url. There is 2 big class instantinated   one for parameter resolving SearchParameterResolver the other one SearchAPIHandler  For API communication How could I achieve this approach properly ?

Comment: Btw, I just want to add this test thing after try catch block. Everything about the canonical url is resolving in resolveUrl().

Comment: Do you have unit tests for SearchParameterBag and SearchService?  That is where I would start.

Comment: SearchParameterBag just getter setters, you may mean SearchParameterResolver, I didn't write everything yet, but I tried to write testable not searchService yet, but also for this I'm trying to make things testable I follow testable code documents.